# javax.persistence.Table.indexes in Tomcat 8.0.32 + Hibernate 4.3

Tags: hibernate, tomcat8

On `Tomcat 8.0.32` I am getting error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()
[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```

I am using:

- Tomcat 8 from Netbeans.
- Hibernate 4.3.x(JPA2.1).
- I also have `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar` in my class path and in `tomcat\lib`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have javax.persistence.jar, then remove it, it is probably conflicting with hibernate jars.